# newpx makes fontspec fail

Tags: fontspec, luaotfload

If I use the newpx package and then load fontspec and try to select a font it fails. See the minimal example below.

The files (compiled with lualatex) for which fontspec font selection fails (by loading newpx before fontspec) with TeX Live 2021 and the packages up to date (via tlmgr) today (2022-03-28) used to work with an earlier TeX Live version (TeX Live 2020, or 2021 but with older versions of the packages, I can't tell exactly when).

I can't tell if the problem is due to newpx or fontspec (or luaotfload or something else).

Could you help me identify the cause, find a workaround and tell me who to report the problem to so that it can be fixed?

Thanks and have a nice day

```
%%%% MWE

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{newpxtext}  % comment newpx and everything is ok
% this used to work with an older version of TeX Live (older version of the packages)
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \usepackage{kurier}  % not needed

\setmainfont{texgyrebonum-regular.otf}  % font selection by file name gives no error but does not select the correct font: newpx font (TeXGyrePagellaX) used instead of TeX Gyre Bonum

\setsansfont{Kurier}  % font selection by font name gives a fontspec error: "The font (Kurier, or any other font selected by font name) cannot be found"

\begin{document}

ABCXYZ

\end{document}

%%%%
```

Comment: What would be the reason to load `newpxtext` and then use a different font?

Comment: it would really help if you would mention what you mean by "it fails". Do you get an error? And if yes which one?

Comment: @egreg: This is for illustration reason of font selection by file name vs by font name. I am using `newpxtext` as my main font but calling other fonts via `fontspec` and it now fails if I use the `newpxtext` package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Actually I put the error (or incorrect behavior) as a comment in the MWE after `\setmainfont{texgyrebonum-regular.otf}` and `\setsansfont{Kurier}`. And I guess this is reproducible for anyone with an up-to-date TeX Live.

Comment: yes, sorry I saw that later. But you should better mention such error messages in the main text, or put them at least above the lines. Error messages that you only see if you scroll are easy to overlook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem should be reported to the `newpxtext` author, but you also shouldn't load the `newpxtext` package if you don't actually want to use it's font.

The reason that font loading fails after `\usepackage{newtxtext}` is that `newtxtext` executes `\defaultfontfeatures` with a bunch of features which really only apply to it's own font, but since they are set as a default they affect all further loaded fonts. Especially it sets the option `Extension = .otf` specifying that all following names should be interpreted as filenames of `.otf` files.

The best fix is not to load `newpxtext` but you can also fix the `\defaultfontfeatures` issue by resetting the default font features: Add `\defaultfontfeatures{}` between loading `newpxtext` and loading another font.

This still leaves the issue that your font change does not actually get applied. That's because the `newpxtext` package expects that it's only loaded when it should actually control the font and therefore changes the font only in `\begin{document}` probably to stop the preamble from interfering. You could probably avoid that by moving `\setmainfont` after `\begin{document}` but at that point you are going through a lot of trouble just to load a package you don't actually want to use...

Comment: Yes my example is a bit confusing but in my non minimal file I actually use `newpx` as the main font. And I have a few calls to other fonts punctually via the `\fontspec` command) which failed as the MWE with Kurier above). I probably should have shown the font selection by file name with `\setmonofont` or a `\fontspec` command in the document instead of `\setmainfont`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the main cause. I'll send an e-mail to the author of `newpx` referring to this answer. In fact as said in my question the behavior of `newpx`, `fontspec` or `luaotfload` must have changed over time because several months ago my file was compiling without problem and lately it produces the above errors.

Comment: I found that `newpxtext` has fixed this issue and you can just use `\usepackage{newpx} \setCJKmainfont{Source Han Serif CN}`, but `newtxtext` has not fixed this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a version of Palatino with `fontspec`, use

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
```

or

```
\setmainfont{Domitian}
```

Both of these are clones of Adobe’s Palatino.  You can also use a version of Palatino that you have installed on your system, such as Palatino Linotype with Microsoft Windows or Office.

If you also want to replace `newtxmath`, load `unicode-math` and then use either

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
```

or

```
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
```

Comment: In fact I replaced `newpxtext` by [`Domitian`](https://ctan.org/pkg/domitian). To have a layout with line breaks / page breaks similar to what I had with `newpxtext` (and the microtypigraphic settings of `spacing`, `stretch` and `shrink` that I had) `Domitian` was more similar to my `newpxtext` than `TeX Gyre Pagella`.