# newtx conflicts with fontspec in TeX Live 2022

Tags: fonts, fontspec, xecjk, newtx, chinese

After upgrading to TeX Live 2022, I found a lot of my previous code broken due to the clash between `newtx` and `fontspec`. Here is a minimal example (The engine is XeLaTeX under Windows):

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % !!!
\usepackage{newtxmath} % !!!
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\begin{document}
    \[ x^2+y^2=z^2 \]

    Test English.

    测试中文。
\end{document}
```

The code will not compile and shows error:

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "TeX Gyre Heros" cannot be found.
...
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Noto Serif CJK SC" cannot be found.
```

However, if I comment out the two lines with `!!!`, then it compiles.

With this A/B test I know that it is the recent (official) support of unicode-engine in `newtx` that breaks my code, because `newtx` uses `fontspec` now. I tried to pass `[nofontspec]` to `newtx` but the font turned out to be wrong.

What exactly is happening here? Any suggestions for fixing all my codes (I use `newtx` with `fontspec` heavily) without doing too much work?

Comment: Are the mentioned fonts installed? And you probably want to note which engine and os you're using

Comment: Yes, they are installed and usable --- confirmed by successful compilation after commenting out ```newtx```. The engine is XeLaTeX under Windows.

Comment: Why do you attempt to run both `\usepackage{newtxtext}` and `\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}`, i.e., why are you trying to set up two rather mutually incompatible text fonts?

Comment: @Mico ```\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}``` specifies the fonts for CJK characters. Even if I remove this line, the file won't compile and says TeX Gyre Heros is not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have observed the same problem with `newpx` and `fontspec` recently. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638757/newpx-makes-fontspec-fail) (and [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638763/263552)). I sent an e-mail to the author of `newpx` (and `newtx`) but didn't get an answer.

Add `\defaultfontfeatures{}` after loading `newtx`.

Comment: Works! Will accept after some delay in case anyone else has other ideas :)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're strongly committed to pursuing the xeCJK approach, I'd like to suggest that you employ the `unicode-math` package and issue suitable `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont`, and `\setmathfont` directives.

Since you're using the Noto Serif SC font family for the main (serif) text font, I wouldn't use Helvetica as the main sans-serif font. Instead, I'd employ the Noto Sans SC font family. If you must use a Times Roman clone as the math font, I'd ditch the `newtxmath` math font and, instead, issue the directive `\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}`.

I compiled the following code with MacTeX2022 and LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif SC}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans SC}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}
Test serif font. 

\textsf{Test sans-serif.} 

$x^2+y^2=z^2$.

测试中文。\quad \textsf{测试中文。}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Agree. I was previous told that ```newtx``` should only be used with a non-unicode engine. Would refactor the code now.