# \sin doesn't call mainfont when just loading newtxmath

Tags: newtxmath, newtx

similar to [DeclareMathOperator does not respect math font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497846/180617) .
Here is my mwe:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}
\usepackage[]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$ \sin x $ 
\end{document}
```

It output

[image]

But my expected output is

[image]

How can I get my expected output when **only** loading `newtxmath` package without `newtxtext`.

#### Edit

The reason why I can't use `newtx` or `newtxtext` package: I'm a `ctex` package user, `newtx(text)` is incompatible with `ctex` package, so I have to set main font myself. I put mwes below, all of them should be compiled with xelatex:

```tex
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
% \usepackage{newtx}
\begin{document}
  测试\textbf{测试}\textit{测试}{\heiti 测试}{\kaishu 测试}
  English\textbf{English}\textit{English}\textbf{\textit{English}}
\end{document}
```

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "SimHei" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.4   测试\textbf{测试}\textit{测试}{\heiti
                                      测试}{\kaishu 测试}
```

If I change `newtxtext` to `newtx`, I'll get

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package fontspec.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.465     \ifnum
                \ntx@id=10\relax % libertinus
```

If I use `nofontspec` or `type1` option to load `newtxtext` package, it will break itself with **xelatex**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[type1]{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
  English\textbf{English}\textit{English}\textbf{\textit{English}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/638757/180617 . But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Try the `newtx` package maintainer!

Comment: @murray well, I'm a `ctex` package user, `newtx(text)` is incompatible with `ctex` package, so I have to set main font myself:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to teach LaTeX what's the `operators` font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\setmainfont{texgyretermes}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
  NFSSFamily=texgyretermes,
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{TU}{texgyretermes}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$ 2\sin x $

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, the most recent versions of NewTX can recognize when XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX are used and you can simply do

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

which will employ a variant of TeX Gyre Termes, but essentially the same.

Comment: In fact, with current `newtx` (since version 1.7), you need only use `\usepackage{newtx}`.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the fixes that I’d usually recommend break with `newtxmath`, which is not very compatible with other packages.  I’d therefore recommend you do one of two things.

#### Cut the Gordian Knot

If you can use `fontspec`, you can use `unicode-math` and load an OpenType math font, instead of `newtxmath`.

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
```

Variations include: TeX Gyre Termes X as a text font closer to `newtxtext`, XITS and XITS Math, or `\usepackage[times]{fontsetup}`.

#### Go Back to Legacy Fonts

The package does work with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
```

If you need Greek or Cyrillic, you might use another font, such as `tempora`.